# parameters in class data type function (php)

Tags: php

when I see parameters in a function in the form of a class name, what does it mean? how can you google it? it is clear that if there is an array in front of a variable, it must be a variable of the array type, but if the class is in front of the variable, what does this mean?

```
public function scopeFilter(Builder $builder, array $filter)
     { /**/ }
```

I tried to google but couldn't find it

Comment: Builder is object of class, array is array if there is no indicated type - then you need to read the function code and deduce what it can be.

Answer (score 1):

It is known as [Type hinting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php) and has been part of the PHP core since version 5.

As per the documentation:

> They ensure that the value is of the specified type at call time, otherwise a TypeError is thrown.

So using your example, if you tried to call your `scopeFilter` function and provide it with arguments that were not a `Builder` and an `array`, you'd get a runtime error.

There are [plenty of articles available](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+type+hint) should you want to read more about type hinting.